# How to fill a dataset with 0s and 1s for values that match in row-column, in R?

Tags: r

I've a dataset in a csv file that looks as follows:

```
 X               Colour Orange Red White Violet Black Yellow Blue
1 1          Orange, Red     NA  NA    NA     NA    NA     NA   NA
2 2                  Red     NA  NA    NA     NA    NA     NA   NA
3 3         White, Black     NA  NA    NA     NA    NA     NA   NA
4 4               Yellow     NA  NA    NA     NA    NA     NA   NA
5 5 Blue, Orange, Violet     NA  NA    NA     NA    NA     NA   NA
```

I'm trying to add 0s and 1s for every row-column match that occurs. The expected out put is:

```
      Colour     Orange Red White   Violet  Black   Yellow  Blue
1   Orange,Red   1       1    0        0      0        0      0
2   Red          0       1    0        0      0        0      0
3   White,Black  0       0    1        0      1        0      0
4   Yellow       0       0    0        0      0        1      0
5   Blue,Orange, 1       0    0        1      0        0      1
    Violet
```

How to achieve this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop across the column names, and check if they're in the pattern using `grepl`:

```
dat[-(1:2)] <-  sapply( colnames(dat[-(1:2)]), grepl, x=dat$Colour  ) + 0

#  X               Colour Orange Red White Violet Black Yellow Blue
#1 1          Orange, Red      1   1     0      0     0      0    0
#2 2                  Red      0   1     0      0     0      0    0
#3 3         White, Black      0   0     1      0     1      0    0
#4 4               Yellow      0   0     0      0     0      1    0
#5 5 Blue, Orange, Violet      1   0     0      1     0      0    1
```

Comment: Beautiful and neat use of grepl and sapply well done bro

Comment: @VigneshKalai - it gives a different output - try `agrepl` maybe

Comment: Yes agrepl also gives the same output but agrep gives the output in 1 or 0 form so i thought of using that instead than adding the answer with 0

Comment: @VigneshKalai  `agrep`, `grep` etc gives the position and the result will be a list due to different lengths.  `sapply( colnames(dat[-(1:2)]), agrep, x=dat$Colour)` , So it will give the error by adding with 0.  Also, the output is not in `1,0`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether you added the NA columns or not. Even without having any identifier NA columns, we can use `strsplit` to split the "Colour" column, apply `mtabulate` on the list output and if needed, rearrange the output based on the column names of 'dat'

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(dat[1:2], mtabulate(strsplit(dat$Colour, ', ')))[names(dat)]
#   X               Colour Orange Red White Violet Black Yellow Blue
#1 1          Orange, Red      1   1     0      0     0      0    0
#2 2                  Red      0   1     0      0     0      0    0
#3 3         White, Black      0   0     1      0     1      0    0
#4 4               Yellow      0   0     0      0     0      1    0
#5 5 Blue, Orange, Violet      1   0     0      1     0      0    1
```

or a similar approach would be to use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(dat[1:2], 'Colour', type='character', fill=0)
```

Comment: Could you explain the process

Comment: @VigneshKalai Added some text.  Hope it helps